# Django: 'CSRF verification failed' only happens on one computer!

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have a strange issue here with my Django app. I implemented the user auth/profiles, and I can log in successfully, etc, with various computers and from three different internet locations. It all works, except for this one computer.

This one computer receives this error when they log in.

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
No CSRF or session cookie.

I tried testing various browsers on this one computer, all get the same error. I even tested logging in on another computer from the same internet, and it works just fine. I believe this test reveals that it is not an internet problem, and it is a general computer setting problem (not specific browser).

I'm afraid that if this error happens with this one computer, if I go live, there may be other computers out there with the same issue. Is there anything I can do to check to see why it is happening only on this one machine, and more importantly, how I would fix it?

I'm hosting the app on some computer using the Django dev server.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strange that it happens on different browsers. Have you checked that cookies are enabled? Have you inspected the contents of cookies?

Comment: Cookies are enabled, still get the issue though. The problem shouldn't happen even of cookies aren't enabled anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the error is misleading.  When I have seen a problem with logins for applications that impact only one computer, but multiple browsers, it has usually been a problem with the date that computer is set to interacting with expiring cookies.

For example, this one computer may be set with a date 1 month into the future and the cookie being sent is being expired instantly because it is only a 90 minute session cookie.

So while it's not even really a Django related answer, check the clock on that computer. :-)